# Install custom Windows 10 iso via Boot Camp

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, bootcamp, install, dual-boot

I am running a non-retina 15' 2012 Macbook Pro with Mojave 1.14.4. I had some apps for work that I can only run on Windows but I am not willing to download the full Windows 10 with all the bloatwares that it has. So I found some reputable custom Windows 10 Lite iso files in hope of having a lighter version of Windows I could use without worrying about Windows update or all its bloatware. Though, Boot Camp Assistant rejected installing the file with this popup:
[image: .]

The iso I'm trying to install is a 64bit iso as well and with some digging, I found that Boot Camp only allows installation of official Windows 10 iso files downloaded straight from Microsoft.
Is there a way I could bypass this pop-up altogether and proceed with my installation? Or if there are any Windows 10 iso that works will be great. Worst case scenario I guess I will have to install the full Windows 10 iso. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are no "reputable custom Windows 10 ISO files".  Every one of them is against the license.

Comment: @Marc: What make you think creating a custom Windows 10 ISO is against some sort of license? Microsoft provide various tools which OEM's use to customize Windows for the PCs they sell. Usually software is added. However, a custom ISO could be created where unnecessary software was removed.

Comment: iranoutofideasfornames: You can use the Boot Camp Assistant to download the Windows Support Software, which contains the drivers for your model Mac. After that, you probably will need to install your version of Windows without further use of the Boot Camp Assistant. For what others have posted, I believe Windows should be installed to BIOS boot. However, since I have never had access to a non-retina 15' 2012 Macbook Pro, I can not confirm this.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Because they can't legally distribute the result.  Any right not explicitly granted is reserved to the copyright holder.    Where would this custom ISO come from?  WarezAreUs.com?

Comment: How do you know these ISO files were distributed? This is not in the OP's question. For all I know, the OP works in an office and the guy next door made the custom Windows ISO. Or, maybe the OP made the ISO using a PC.

Comment: @MarcWilson Well that I figured. "reputable" to me is just that it has a large enough of a community and friends that recommend it to me, enough that I feel safe to use it

Comment: @DavidAnderson I see, that's an option as well. Are there any particular risks I should note of? Maybe in the installation process or even erasing the Windows partition after I'm done with my work. I'm not really the most tech-savvy guy so I want to go for the safest option to not burden anyone, or even perhaps modifying windows after installing? But maybe that is just as risky.

Answer (score 0):

Boot Camp will not let you install any Windows ISO that isn't directly downloaded from Microsoft. It is quite annoying, I know.
So you need to use Bootcamp just to download all the Drivers and other files, which Boot camp does allow.
Then you will have to make your own Bootable USB/DVD and partition your drive and then install Windows Lite.

Comment: ....yeah, that was what I compromised on. Until Boot Camp just screwed me over and doesn't allow me to install Windows Support Software even though I untick it, it keeps forcing itself upon me. Making me flash a windows 10 iso into my USB and try to install it again, only for it to show the error "Windows could not prepare the computer to boot into the next phase of installation". *Sigh*

Comment: Don't use bootcamp past the first step. All you have to do is open bootcamp and DO NOT click 'continue' instead in the menu bar, click "Action" and there is the option to download only the required files. Also you can't use bootcamp at all past this one step. You will have to use the terminal.

Comment: JordanDavid: You wouldn't happen to know if Windows 10 should be installed to BIOS or UEFI boot?

Comment: It depends, but unless your PC is very old it can use UEFI, but Windows usually requires an MBR boot scheme for older versions.